# Escape character in LESS CSS inserts unwanted spaces

Tags: css, escaping, less

I am trying to write the LESS code corresponding to the following CSS code for generating gradient in IE.

```
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff9600',endColorstr='#ff6900');
```

following is the LESS code:

```
.gradient(@start_color, @end_color)
{
    filter:~"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='"@start_color~"',endColorstr='"@end_color~"')";
}
.gradient(#ff9600,#ff6900)
```

on compilation it gives the following CSS code:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=' #ff9600 ', endColorstr=' #ff6900 ');
```

As you can see there are spaces inserted on both sides of the color values because of which IE doesn't read the colors correctly.

I have compiled the LESS code using http://crunchapp.net/ as well as http://winless.org/ and both are providing the same results. Is there a hack to avoid these spaces. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use variable interpolation instead of ending the string and restarting it.

E.g.

~"bar@{name}foo"

And no spaces will be inserted.

Answer (score 3):

I am using LESS.app ([www.lesscss.org](http://www.lesscss.org))...

I just put

```
filter: progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='@{start}', endColorstr='@{stopColor}', GradientType=0);
```

and it gets compiled properly as below:

```
filter: progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#76787a', endColorstr='#9d9ea0', GradientType=0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that familiar with [LESS](http://lesscss.org/); however, from what I can see on their page:

```
.class {
  filter: ~"ms:alwaysHasItsOwnSyntax.For.Stuff()";
}
```

suggests that there should be no `~` attached to the variables and that if you were trying to pass single quotes through, it would be `"'@var'"` instead of `'"@var"'` With the single quotes inside instead of outside.  I did a little more research here, and think this is an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: this doesn't work as it would make the compiler treat the variable name as a string instead of a variable and the variable name would show up in the compiled css.